# people liars or trustworthy

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a visitor that meets A and B.We have trustworth and liars.
A declares that he is like B.
B declares that one of them is only trustworth.

So I have solved this exercise with truth table

A: trustworthy so p
B: trustworthy  so q (cause he is saying that one of them is trustworth)
I have the table

```
p        q       p  ^ q
true    true      lie
true     lie      lie 
lie      true     lie
lie      lie      true
```

from their  statement we have true and true  so both of them are liars.What the visitor assume ?

> 1)A and B trustworth 2)A trustworth and B liar 3)A liar and B
> trustworth 4)both liars

I find 4.both liars
is it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i think is better now

Comment: If both are liars then it would mean that either 0 or 2 of them are trustworthy (B) and it would mean that A is not like B, i.e. exactly one is trustworthy, therefore they can't both be liars as it leads to a contradiction

Comment: The answer is that A is a liar and B tells the truth. Your truth table does not answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user619755 said, you can see:

If A is trustworthy, so it said the truth, therefore B become trustworthy like it and say the truth only, but it contradict with its statement, since there is 2 trustworthy**, hence A can't be trustworthy.**

If B is liar, its statement become wrong, so A can't be trustworthy, therefore it also its statement become wrong, but it contradict with both of them being like each other (liar)**, hence B can't be liar.**

Now the only condition remains:

**A is liar and B is trustworthy,** So they aren't like each other, as we expect from liarness of A, also there is just one trustworthy, as we expect from trustworthiness of B. Conditions are compatible. So it's the answer.

Comment: Already when we know that A can't be trustworthy, it follows that "B is like A" is false, hence B must be trustworthy

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are right, but I prefer to show every one directly, although you solution is shorter and better in some way.